# URL update in jsf 2.2

Tags: navigation, jsf-2.2

I am trying to learn navigation (Page Forward vs Page Redirect) in jsf 2.2. I came across [this](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-page-forward-vs-page-redirect/)  problem of URL update in jsf. I have written some tests and the URL is always update in my case.

**page 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                template="components/defaultLayout.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="bodyClass" value="container body-nomargin" />

    <ui:define name="body">


        <h1>Welcome </h1>


        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="col-md-12">

            <h:form>
                <h:link outcome="detail" value="some value"> </h:link>
            </h:form>


        </h:panelGroup>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

**detail page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                template="components/defaultLayout.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="bodyClass" value="container body-nomargin" />

    <ui:define name="body">

        <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

1) Does this issue of URl not being updated even exists in jsf 2.2 anymore or am i referring to an outdated source here (source mentions it is for jsf 2.0 but i am guessing things would be the same for jsf 2.2. )?

Comment: Off-topic: don't mix jsf 2.2 and pre jsf-2.2 namespaces. Might result in undefined behaviour

Comment: @Kukeltje So are you saying that this was the behavior in jsf 2.0 but does not exist in jsf 2.2? 
Also, can you kindly share a link for jsf 2.2 namespaces?

Comment: @Kukeltje How am i mixing the namespaces? Sorry i am new to jsf

Comment: This: _xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"_ is pre jsf-2.2, and this: _
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"_ is jsf 2.2. For a link about the namespaces... Lots of info on google (and adding 'stackoverflow' in the search helps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see this behaviour since you use an `h:link` which according to [the specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/link.html) (emphasis mine)

> Execute the Algorithm to obtain the URL to which the user-agent should issue a **GET** request when clicked.

So you effectively 'fixed' the problem by not creating it in the first place.

See also bullet 1 in the answer

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)